# Pass ID in URL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

### Here's where I'm trying to get the ID

```
 function addCliente($tipo_pessoa, $popup=null, $dados = null) {
        $tipo_login = $this->session->userdata('tipo_login');
        if ($this->session->userdata('logado') == true && $tipo_login == '1') {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            if ($tipo_pessoa == 1) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpf', 'CPF', 'required|callback_verifica_cpf');
            } else if ($tipo_pessoa == 2) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnpj', 'CNPJ', 'required|callback_verifica_cnpj');
            }
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->returnCadCliente($tipo_pessoa);
            } else {
                $id_endereco = $this->cadEndereco($tipo_pessoa);
                if ($tipo_pessoa == '1') {
                    $id_pessoa = $this->cadPessoaFisica();
                    $id_banco = $this->cadastroDadosBancarios();
                    $id_contato = $this->cadastroContato();
                    $id_cadastroAnexo = $this->cadastroAnexo();
                    $id_cadastroAtendimento = $this->cadastroAtendimento();
                } else if ($tipo_pessoa == '2') {
                    $id_pessoa = $this->cadPessoaJuridica();
                    $id_banco = $this->cadastroDadosBancarios();
                    $id_contato = $this->cadastroContato();
                    $id_cadastroAnexo = $this->cadastroAnexo();
                    $id_cadastroAtendimento = $this->cadastroAtendimento();
                }
                $limite_credito = null;
                if ($this->input->post('limite_credito')) {
                    $limite_credito = $this->input->post('limite_credito');
                }
                $id_cliente = $this->cadCliente($tipo_pessoa);
                $data_cad = date("d/m/Y");
                $hora_cad = date("H:i:s");
                if ($id_cadastro = $this->cadastroComum($limite_credito, (int) $tipo_pessoa, $id_pessoa, 1, $id_cliente, $id_endereco, $data_cad, $hora_cad)) {
                    $this->cadastroHistorico('Cliente cadastrado', $id_cadastro, $data_cad, $hora_cad);
                    if ($popup == '1') {
                        $this->mensagemAlerta("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", 1, "home/cadastroOrcamentoVenda/" . $this->input->post('matricula'), (int) $tipo_pessoa);    
                    } else {
                    //$this->mensagemAlerta("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", 1, "home/cadastroCliente/", (int) $tipo_pessoa);
```

- I call alteraçãoClientePf here

```
                    $this->mensagemAlerta("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", 1, "home/alteracaoClientePf/" . $this->input->post('id_cadastro'), (int) $tipo_pessoa);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->mensagemAlerta("Erro ao cadastrar cliente, tente novamente!", 0, "cadastro/returnCadCliente/", (int) $tipo_pessoa);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dados['mensagem'] = null;
            $this->load->view('login/head');
            $this->load->view('login/formLogin', $dados);
            $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }

    }
```

### This is the function I call when requesting the ID

```
function alteracaoClientePf($id_cadastro, $dados = null) {
    $tipo_login = $this->session->userdata('tipo_login');
    if ($this->session->userdata('logado') == true && $tipo_login == '1') {
        $dadosCliente['dados'] = $this->lista->retornaDadosClientePf($id_cadastro);
        $dadosCliente['banco'] = $this->adm->returnBancos();
        $dadosCliente['contas_bancarias'] = $this->lista->retornaContas($id_cadastro);
        $dadosCliente['contatos'] = $this->lista->retornaContatos($id_cadastro);
        $dadosCliente['anexos'] = $this->lista->retornaAnexos($id_cadastro);
        $dadosCliente['atendimentos'] = $this->lista->retornaAtendimentos($id_cadastro);
        $dadosCliente['historico'] = $this->lista->retornaHistorico($id_cadastro);
        $this->load->view('admin/head');
        $dadosBarra['dadosB'] = $this->financeiro->listaContas();
        $this->load->view('admin/barraSuperior', $dadosBarra);
        $dadosLogo['logo'] = $this->adm->retornaLogo();
        $this->load->view('admin/menu', $dadosLogo);
        $this->load->view('admin/alteracoes/alterar_cliente_pf', $dadosCliente);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
    } else {
        $dados['mensagem'] = null;
        $this->paginas($dados);
    }
}
```

### That's the error I'm getting

> Message: Too few arguments to function Home::alteracaoClientePf(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_financas_old_atual\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and at least 1 expected
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_financas_old_atual\application\controllers\Home.php
>
> Line Number: 1184

Comment: The code you posted calls `mensagemAlerta()`, not `alteracaoClientePf()` so it's not where the error is thrown.

Comment: But I need to call the Alert and send it to the AlteracaoClientePf page 

I want is to concatenate the ID in the URL

Comment: If you read the error message, it says that you're not passing in any arguments when you're calling `alteracaoClientePf()`, while that function expects at least one argument. Unless we see where and how you're trying to call _that_ function, we can't really help you more than the error message already has. We don't know you're application. We only know what you tell and show us.

Comment: I changed the question and added the function. It got better ?

Comment: This is a whole mountain of code for what boils down to "you forgot to pass an argument to a function that requires one".

Comment: ...and no where in that mountain of code are you calling the function `alteracaoClientePf()`, which the error message is all about.

Comment: I made a comment on the line of code

Comment: I m calling here $this->mensagemAlerta("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", 1, "home/alteracaoClientePf/" . $this->input->post('id_cadastro'), (int) $tipo_pessoa);